# Refreshing or closing the message currently open in the UI

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I just finished writing my second gmail addon :) which was quite more simple than my first one, a couple of hours to do it only, but there's a simple thing missing that I spent another couple of hours trying to solve with no success.

Basically this script makes some changes to the currently open message in the UI but that do not appear in the UI when the script ends. So the question is, is there any way of refreshing or closing the message currently open in the UI?

I understand the scripts run in the server, but there are some "refresh" methods that I hoped it worked, but it seems they don't.

I tried both GmailApp and the Gmail API but no success.

Any ideia?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the 'refresh()' method of GmailMessage class? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#refresh

Comment: I did, I tried all that I could find, GmailApp.refreshThread(), GmailMessage.refresh() and GmailThread.referesh(), none refresh the message open in the UI and I have conflict results when closing the msgs and going back to the inbox, sometimes updates sometimes don't. Cheers.